# How to make jest not distinguish between negative zero and positive zero?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

What is the best way to make Jest pass the following test:

```
test('example', () => {
  expect(0).toEqual(-0);
});
```

I don't want to distinguish negative zero and positive zero.

---

Maybe I should use some other function instead of `.toEqual`? Or I should replace all blocks like this:

```
expect(a).toEqual(b);
```

to

```
expect(a === 0 ? +0 : a).toEqual(b === 0 ? +0 : b);
```

?

Comment: How about writing your own [matcher](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectextendmatchers)?

Comment: Looks like it is the only solution. Thank you. It is totally unclear to me why they make `.toEqual` function so inconvenient.

Comment: I'm not sure about the reasoning. All I could say is that it is an explicit part of the [implementation](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/fec36ae1e34537074d0e57a5aa477457be5b952f/packages/expect/src/jasmine_utils.js#L78).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can slightly sidestep the issue by doing your logic inside of the `expect` function:

```
expect(0).toEqual(-0); // fails
expect(0 === -0).toEqual(true); // ugly, but it works!
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution for lists and nested objects would be to convert them to JSON and back.

```
const negativeObject = { list: [-0, -0] };
const positiveObject = { list: [0, 0] };

expect(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(negativeObject)))
  .toEqual(positiveObject);
```

This works because `JSON.stringify()` converts -0 to 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.toBeCloseTo(number, numDigits)` matcher:

```
expect(-0).toBeCloseTo(0, 10);
```